# >Видно, был тот день самым ярким днем, и считали мы, / : / — нет конца ему

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> Видно, был тот день самым ярким днем, и считали мы, нет конца ему.

> Видно, был тот день самым ярким днем, и считали мы — нет конца ему.

> Видно, был тот день самым ярким днем, и считали мы: нет конца ему.

Comment: Лучше всего использовать двоеточие, изъяснительные отношения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все три варианта – "правильно".

Я выбираю с тире – как более эмоциональное ("мы" ведь понимали, что всякому, даже чёрному дню приходит конец).

С запятой и двоеточием спокойнее - просто информация, ничего личного.

Comment: Ну да, по факту так. Плюс ставлю.